Please suggest a mechanism that will allow you to change the tension force of an elastic band
Please suggest a mechanism that will allow one to change the tension force of an elastic band. Criteria:

It should be compact.
It should not change its dimensions depending on the tension force
of the band.
It should have a system for fixing the band in a particular
position. The organs with which the tension will be adjusted should
be in one place during use.
It should be entirely mechanical, without the use of electronics.


a windlass ....

An explanation of what you are trying to achieve with details of the device will stop us wasting time with suggestions you then state won't work.

Use a similar worm screw that is used by string instruments to tighten their strings. These are both compact, relatively cheap and easy to get hands on. Your situation is somewhat analogious to the instrument anyway.
If this is too small then just use any other worm screw. Worms screws can generally not be backdriven, so they dont loosen over time as such, except maybe by vibration. The elasticity of your band may loosen over time.

Its obviously hard to say whats compact in this case.

This works if the band is not a loop and you are not going to move the system nor apply repeating changing forces which can make it to oscillate
I guess at first there's some unknown and sometimes changing external load which excludes all simple "stretch-with-a-screw" systems. Make it self-adjusting for example by letting the band be tensioned by a weight which pulls one band end downwards over a freely rolling pulley. The force stays practically the same if there's enough room for the weight to fall when the band gets stretched (assuming the weight is massive when compared that part of the band which is at the fall-side of the pulley, the pulley rolling friction is negligible and there's no wind)
You can also try a constant force spring, but adjusting the force is not easy. Constant force springs have been used in clocks and toys hundreds of years. Gas springs have nearly constant force, too.
Tension force can be adjusted by having an adjustable lever if the primary force generation outputs a constant force.
ADD: your statement "the tension adjustment organs should be in one place" excludes all mechanical systems because those organs must have some motion to change the force - for example you must take off some material from the weight to decrease its gravity force. Or you must move a counter piston in an adjustable gas spring or adjust a lever. To get something concrete you should give some limit values or preferably you should reveal the actual design goal.

Is this "compact"?

You mean the pulley and weight - that depends on the reference. It can be compact enough for something
